# Grep output lines in array

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to put my grep output lines into an array as elements.

The output after grep (files are stored in /asd folder for example)

```
test.mp4
test2.mp4
```

So here's how it should be at the end:

```
arr_name[0] = test.mp4
arr_name[1] = test2.mp4
```

Here's my code so far:

```
arr_name=( $(cd ~/asd; ls -tr | grep -v total | head -2) )
```

Can you please help me to resolve the mistake?

Comment: Looks okay; how are you testing to see if it is working?  echo ${arr_name[0]} etc... should work.

Comment: When i run the script it says Syntax error: "(" unexpected for the line where the array is

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `grep` here and avoid parsing output of `ls` by using `-I` option of `ls`.

```
# To list all files except *total*
ls -I '*total*' -tr

# to read all the listed entries in an array
mapfile -t  arr < <(ls -I '*total*' -tr)

# to get first 2 entries
echo "${arr[@]:0:2}"

# to store 2 entries in an array
parr=("${arr[@]:0:2}")

# check your results
declare -p parr
```

Comment: Nice. Could you elaborate  on how `mapfile -t  arr < <(ls -I '*total*' -tr)` works here?

Comment: I used `mapfile` to populate the array with output of `ls` command. Command substitution may also work as an Annemarie but will break if file names have spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set

```
IFS='
'
```

Then the lines will be saved correctly